# writing a csv file using KBcsv writer

Tags: c#

I am trying to write into csv file using Kent.Boogaart.KBCsv, cant figure out what could be the problem?

Piece of code:

```
private static void SaveCSV(List<AData> items,string fName)
{
   using (CsvWriter wr = new CsvWriter(fName))
    {
        wr.ValueSeparator = ';';
        foreach (AData item in items)
        {
            wr.WriteDataRecord(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:
The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\myname\Documents\something.txt' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: can you also show how or where you are reading and or using the .txt file.. perhaps a StreamReader Error in regards to how you are reading from that particular file.. can you provide more relevant code..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in use by another process.  That means either:
You have the file opened elsewhere and therefor cannot modify it (make sure to close Notepad and other text editors)
Possibly a mixed up complaint about Admin rights.  C:\User should be protected by Windows 7 and if your process isn't elevated, it won't be allowed to access it.  Try writing to:
C:\something.txt
Instead.

Comment: Tried writing to c:\something.txt and it worked. Thank you Akintunde.